# How can i execute comm Linux command in Python

Tags: python, linux, bash

I want to extract lines from File1 which are not present in File2

File1

```
a  
b  
c
```

File2

```
a  
c
```

so the output should be:

```
b
```

One possible command in bash is:

```
comm -23 <(sort File1) <(sort File2) > File
```

And it works perfectly well in bash, but I don't know how correctly to implement in Python.

I've tried with

```
import os  
os.system("comm -23 <(sort File1) <(sort File2) > File")
```

And is not working.
Any hint?

Comment: Do yourself a favour and use `subprocess`

Comment: How it will be subprocess implementation? @padraic-cunningham

Comment: Why bother? You can implement this kind of logic natively in Python so, so very easily...

Comment: @josifoski, i meant more in general, I agree with charles, doing it with just python is a whole lot simpler

Comment: Some says, linux in ♡

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you **must** use a shell, do it safely:

```py
subprocess.call(['bash', '-c',
    'comm -23 <(sort "$1") <(sort "$2") >"$3"', '_',
    infile1_name, infile2_name, outfile_name])
```

That is to say: Instead of passing the filenames in as part of your code, pass them as out-of-band variables such that their names can't be interpreted by the shell.

---

Continuing to use `sort` and `comm`, but doing so *without* a shell, it looks more like:

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, call

p_sort1 = Popen(['sort'], stdin=open(infile1_name, 'r'), stdout=PIPE)
p_sort2 = Popen(['sort'], stdin=open(infile2_name, 'r'), stdout=PIPE)
p_comm = Popen(['comm', '-23',
                f'/dev/fd/{p_sort1.stdout.fileno()}',
                f'/dev/fd/{p_sort2.stdout.fileno()}',
               ],
               pass_fds=[p_sort1.stdout.fileno(), p_sort2.stdout.fileno()],
               stdout=open('outfile_name', 'w'),
)

# Close file descriptors on the Python end so only the spawned processes have
# open copies
p_sort1.stdout.close()
p_sort2.stdout.close()

# Let the pipeline run, with comm reading output from the two sort processes
p_comm.wait()
```

---

All that said, doing this in pure Python (as in [MaxNoe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34426338/14122)) is ideal; the only major advantage one gets from the above is `sort`'s ability to work with contents larger than RAM (by splitting into temporary files and doing a merge-sort to combine them).

Comment: @josifoski, ...I've finally come back and built an implementation that still uses `sort` and `comm` but without a shell.

Answer (score 9):

How about a pure python solution?

```
with open('file1', 'r') as f:
    lines1 = set(f.read().splitlines())

with open('file2', 'r') as f:
    lines2 = set(f.read().splitlines())

print(lines1.difference(lines2))
```

Or with less memory overhead:

```
with open('file1') as f, open('file2') as f2:
    lines1 = set(map(str.rstrip, f))
    print(lines1.difference(map(str.rstrip, f2)))
```

Comment: tnx :) +1, will reconsider will be pure python solution or bash style

Comment: why not just call set on the file objects instead of creating multiple copies of the data?

Comment: Depends on if you want endlines in the sets. I didn't want them.

Comment: `set(map(str.rstrip,f))` `set(itertools.imap(str.rstrip,f))`

Comment: And whats the advantange of that? Faster?

Comment: it does not create potentially huge amounts of data in memory, you can also  completely forget about calling set on the second file and `set(map(str.rstrip,f)).difference(map(str.rstrip, f2))`, the point of using `difference` is that you don't need the second iterable to be a set.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because you need use `bash` run the command:

```
os.system("bash -c 'comm -23 <(sort File1) <(sort File2) > File'")
```

Normally, [`os.system()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) use `sh` run the command. But however, there's little different between `bash` and `sh`.

So in this case, I used `bash -c 'command'` call `bash` run the command. Then it could works.

From the manual of `bash`:

> `-c`     If the `-c` option is present, then commands are read from the first non-option argument `command_string`.
>
> If there are arguments after the `command_string`, they are assigned to the positional parameters, starting with `$0`.

Comment: There's security risk to doing it this way -- look at what happens if one of your filenames contains the literal string `$(rm -rf ~)`.

Comment: so crossplatform is better then donkey direction. Tnx for advice

Comment: @josifoski, ..."donkey direction"?

Comment: only preffering linux kind of thinking. It will be some difficulties if not crossplatforming implemented in any program

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Yep, however actually I rarely use `os.system` because we always can do anything in Python instead of use Linux commands :)

Comment: Good one :) @kevin-guan

Comment: Note that `os.system(...)` calls `sh -c ...`, so invoking `os.system('bash -c ...')` is in turn `sh -c 'bash -c ...'`; wouldn't it be better to _only_ call bash, and not have a separate copy of sh invoking it?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Actually **yes**; therefore I had upvoted both yours and Max's answer years ago. But my answer explains *why* OP's code doesn't work and *how* to get the job done in the same way. So it isn't the best solution to OP's question, but a useful answer I'd say.